# How to use sed to delete everything but a random string

Tags: text-processing, sed

Guys I'm having a problem.

I have sample data

```
2021-04-15 07:47:34        629 deveon3/10d/023aad3eab0a035aef3771c9220940e200a00000000242e5_0.gt
```

and I need just

```
023aad3eab0a035aef3771c9220940e200a00000000242e5
```

I try

```
grep _0.gt test.txt | sed "s/.* \(.*\) \(...\)\/\(.*\)_0.gt/\1|\2|\3/g"  > test.dat
```

But I'm getting the same output, no difference

What I'm expecting is if I have

```
2018-10-20 19:34:23    1668004 000/02001386c62785e42231c679c614228a04000090022ff989_0.gt
2018-10-20 21:18:58    1694936 000/02001386c62785e72231c679c614228a040000000232d761_0.gt
2018-10-20 23:59:40    1828575 000/020057386c6278e72231c679c644228a04000000023696fb_0.gt
```

To get output

```
1668004|000|02001386c62785e72231c679c614228a04000000015528dd
1694936|000|02001386c62785e72231c679c614228a040000000166bca7
1828575|000|02001386c62785e72231c679c614228a04000000022f8f33
```

or just

```
02001386c62785e72231c679c614228a04000000015528dd
02001386c62785e72231c679c614228a040000000166bca7
02001386c62785e72231c679c614228a04000000022f8f33
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing your thinking: What you want is not a random string, but parts of a string between one (or more) identifiable points (constraints). Getting the "|000|" part seems easy: before it is at least one space (four spaces in all the example inputs) followed by  numeric digits ([0-9]{7}) and then exactly one space; then the three digits ([0-9]{3}, which are always 0 in your sample) followed by a '/'. Getting the last part is easy, too: it cmes after the '/' and is everything (presumably hex value, [0-9a-fA-F]+) up to the '_' .

Comment: Your output is not in sync with your stated inputs. Check n post the corrected Output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the data between the last `/` and the `_` in the fourth whitespace-delimited field on each line:

```
$ awk '{ sub(".*/","",$4); sub("_.*","",$4); print $4 }' file
02001386c62785e42231c679c614228a04000090022ff989
02001386c62785e72231c679c614228a040000000232d761
020057386c6278e72231c679c644228a04000000023696fb
```

This uses `sub()` twice to trim off anything in the fourth field that occurs before the last `/` and after the `_`.  It then prints what's left of that field.

Using `sed` instead, and assuming that there are no other `/` characters *after* the data that we're interested in:

```
$ sed 's|.*/||; s/_.*//' file
02001386c62785e42231c679c614228a04000090022ff989
02001386c62785e72231c679c614228a040000000232d761
020057386c6278e72231c679c644228a04000000023696fb
```

If you want additional information from the third field, and want to change the delimiters to `|`, you could use `awk` like so:

```
$ awk -v OFS='|' '{ gsub("/",OFS,$4); sub("_.*","",$4); print $3,$4 }' file
1668004|000|02001386c62785e42231c679c614228a04000090022ff989
1694936|000|02001386c62785e72231c679c614228a040000000232d761
1828575|000|020057386c6278e72231c679c644228a04000000023696fb
```

This first changes all `/` in the fourth field to whatever `OFS` is (it's the output field separator and we set it to `|` on the command line). Then we trim off anything after `_` as before and print the third and the modified fourth field.

With `sed`, this would be doable, albeit a bit awkward:

```
$ sed 's/\([^[:blank:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\{2\}//; s/_.*//; y/\/ /||/' file
1668004|000|02001386c62785e42231c679c614228a04000090022ff989
1694936|000|02001386c62785e72231c679c614228a040000000232d761
1828575|000|020057386c6278e72231c679c644228a04000000023696fb
```

or using the non-standard `-E` option to be able to use extended regular expressions:

```
$ sed -E 's/([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){2}//; s/_.*//; y/\/ /||/' file
1668004|000|02001386c62785e42231c679c614228a04000090022ff989
1694936|000|02001386c62785e72231c679c614228a040000000232d761
1828575|000|020057386c6278e72231c679c644228a04000000023696fb
```

This first deletes the first two fields and the whitespace that comes after them, and then deletes all text after the `_`.  Finally, it changes all spaces and `/` into `|`.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'[_/ ]+' '{ print $5 }' infile
```

---

```
awk -F'[_/ ]+' -v OFS="|" '{ print $3, $4, $5 }' infile
```